# one to one within a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, relational-database, relationship

I'd like to assign a primary role to a user with many roles and I'm wondering what method is preferable, if any. Either to make a `primary_role_id` column in the users table or add an `is_primary` column in the pivot table:

Users:

| id | name | primary_role_id here? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alice | 2 |
| 2 | bob | 1 |

Roles:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | super |
| 2 | admin |

Role User:

| user_id | role_id | OR is_primary here? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | true |
| 1 | 2 | false |
| 2 | 1 | false |
| 2 | 2 | true |

Comment: The canonical answer is that the "primary role" is a property of the user. If that's the case, it should be a column on the `users` table, not on `role_user`. The `users` table should also have a FK to `role_user` table on (id, primary_role_id). However, many real databases don't allow this kind of relationship (notable exceptions are Oracle and PostgreSQL, kudos to them).

Comment: Thanks @TheImpaler! Quick question, it looks like your experience with SQL is extensive. Can you recommend a good book on sql database design?

Comment: @TheImpaler. Circular references are prohibited in the *Relational Model*. A freeware suite that allows it, is, by definition, anti-Relational.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA "Circular references are prohibited in the Relational Model" -- Interesting statement! Can you point me to any documentation on it? I would agree that relational algebra does not promote them. However, the SQL Standard does allow it with all provisions for constraint management. To me they are quite useful to maintain the quality of the data.

Comment: @TheImpaler  *[Relational Model](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf)* §1.4 Normal Form (1).  **Tree** = Directed Acyclic Graph = no circular references.  It does not matter whether people like it or not, what matters is whether it is correct.  The SQL Standard *now* allows it because they bowed to the political pressure from the "academics".  SQL allows a lot of anti-Relational concepts.

Answer (score 2):

#### Requirement

It is simple, but not quite that simple.  What you really want is:

- each `User` is permitted 1-to-n `Roles`

  - of that set, one `RoleUser` is primary
    [image]

Therefore:

- the `IsPrimary` indicator has to be in `RoleUser`
- you need a `CHECK` Constraint on `RoleUser`, that calls a Function, to ensure that there is just 1 `IsPrimary` `Role` per `User`.
- That is an ordinary capability in Standard SQL, available in genuine SQL Platforms, not possible in the freeware.

#### Requirement is Not

- each `User` is permitted 1-to-n `Roles`
- each `User` has 1 primary `Role`

  - which leads to maintenance complexity: the set is in one place, the indicator for the set in another.  The Function required checks that the `User` has the `Role` in `RoleUser` that is declared as `PrimaryRoleId`.
  - which is inferior and incorrect
  - the "User has one-to-one PrimaryRole" is true as a result, but not as a declarative.
    [image]